# Error with md-card

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

When i try to display text in mobile device mode, it goes out of `md-card`,
it also doesn't work in codepen.io. Use `md-card-content` doesn't change the situation.

```html
<md-card>
  <md-card-header class="md-whiteframe-1dp">
    <md-title style="color:#3865a0"><b>xx</b></md-title>
  </md-card-header>
  <div style="margin:10px">
  <p>thisisextthathouldbevisuafhdffkdhakfgdkgkgfkgsgkfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgggfgfggfgffggfgfg</p>
  </div>
</md-card>
```

Comment: what do you mean "goes out of `md-card`"?  and can you list the codepen that has this example so we can see what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
<md-card>
  <md-card-header class="md-whiteframe-1dp">
    <md-title style="color:#3865a0"><b>xx</b></md-title>
  </md-card-header>
  <md-card-content>
      <div style="margin:10px">
      <p>thisisextthathouldbevisuafhdffkdhakfgdkgkgfkgsgkfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgggfgfggfgffggfgfg</p>
      </div>
  </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS on the `<p>` tag - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/qaObOp)

Markup

```
<p id="myText">thisisextthathouldbevisuafhdffkdhakfgdkgkgfkgsgkfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgggfgfggfgffggfgfg</p>
```

CSS

```
#myText {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```